# SwiftUI why is this API call not working for me?

Tags: swift, swiftui

So I am trying to grab some json Data, decode that and put it in a struct.

```
import SwiftUI

struct Response : Codable{
    var results: [Result]
}

struct Result: Codable{
    var achievements: Result2

}
struct Result2 : Codable{
    var bedwars_stats : Int
}
VStack{
                    ForEach(results, id: .achievements.bedwars_stats){ item in
                        Text("(item.achievements.bedwars_stats)")

                    }
                }
.task{
            await loadData()
        }
```

and finally this function:

```
func loadData() async{
        guard let url = URL(string: url) else{
            print("bad url")
            return
        }
        do {
            let (data, _) = try await URLSession.shared.data(from: url)

            if let decodedRespose = try? JSONDecoder().decode(Response.self, from: data){
                results = decodedRespose.results
            }
        } catch{
            print("bad")
        }
    }
```

[Pic of json](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ke44r.png)
And I'm trying to get only bedwars_stats and I just don't fully understand what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: what errors do you get? on what lines? Post the json data as text, not bits of a picture. Better still, if possible, show the url you are trying to reach. Most of the time issues are due to your `Response` model not matching the json data, for example, the server is sending you a different data, maybe even an error message. Show a complete example code that highlights your problem.

Comment: I can't include the full link because it has my API key, I believe that the problem is 99% the structs not fitting the json structure but I can't fully understand what's wrong. Here is the first part of the json: "success":true,"player":{"_id":"538821e2fa32dc52692cf8cb","achievements":{"bedwars_stats":10,"arena_climb_the_ranks":1034 so it goes inside player, then achievements then from inside achievements that's where what I want is (bedwars_stats)

Comment: show enough (real) json data that includes the `bedwars_stats`, so we can make sense of it.

Comment: There is no `results` in your json data, why do you have this in your `Response`?

Comment: '{
  "success": true,
  "player": {
    "_id": "538821e2fa32dc52692cf8cb",
    "achievements": {
      "arena_bossed": 10,
      "bedwars_stats": 1034,
      "arena_gladiator": 7,
      "arena_gotta_wear_em_all": 3,
      "blitz_coins": 11006,
      "blitz_kills": 161,
      "general_coins": 164949,
      "general_wins": 1894,
      "walls_coins": 1188,
      "walls_kills": 46,
'
I don't know how I can show much more but bedwars_stats is the second entry in achievements here, there are first 2 objects success and player then player has 72 objects so it's quite a bit.

Comment: What am I supposed to call it then? I thought that the name didn't really matter so should I change that results to actually I just noticed player isn't even in the struct here

Comment: Okay well I tried changing results to player but it still doesn't work I still am having trouble seeing how this json structure is supposed to work within Swift

Comment: add `print(String(data: data, encoding: .utf8))` just after
 `let (data, _) = try await URLSession.shared.data(from: url)` and
 show us a good section of the json data you get, from the very beginning.
 Then we can create the appropriate models.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

according to your bits of json, these are the models you should have:

```
struct ApiResponse : Codable{
    var success: Bool
    var player: Player
}

struct Player : Codable{
    var _id: String
    var achievements: Achievements
}

struct Achievements : Codable{
    var bedwars_stats: Int?
    var arena_climb_the_ranks: Int?
    // others
}
```

and decode the server response like this:

```
 if let decodedRespose = try? JSONDecoder().decode(ApiResponse.self, from: data){
    print("\n---> decodedRespose: \(decodedRespose)")
 }
```

"...I thought that the name didn't really matter..", yes they do matter a lot, they must match. You can use `enum CodingKeys` for that as well.

Comment: Thanks yea that worked and I don't know why I thought the names don't matter, also one more tiny question, from what I know await and async just "sleep" so my UI will keep getting drawn and stuff after calling the await loadData and it'll wake up when I get a response, but what if I want to wait? I have a navigationlink but I only wanna proceed if the api call was successful otherwise I wanna stay in the navigationview how would I be able to do something if its an async function?

Comment: NavigationLink{
                    Tab()
                } label:
                {
                    ZStack{
                        RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: 5)
                            .fill(.gray)
                            .frame(width: 200, height: 50)

                        Text("Search")
                            .foregroundColor(.white)
                            .task{
                                await loadData()



                    }
                }
            } 
This is the navigationlink and I wanna go to the navlink only if

Comment: The api call was successful and I found the data I needed

Answer (score 1):

Generally speaking, the best way to 1, make it legible, and two, parse JSON with `Codable` is to simply follow the name & type of a JSON response in your code. For example, given this JSON, how would your `Codable` object look?

```
{
  "array": [
    1,
    2,
    3
  ],
  "boolean": true,
  "null": null,
  "number": 123,
  "object": {
    "a": "b",
    "c": "d",
    "e": "f"
  },
  "string": "Hello World"
}
```

Your codable, if you follow the type and name, it'll keep things nice and clear.

**NOTE** your variable names should be the name of your properties. So instead of `someArray` it would be `array` because that's the JSON properties name. I didn't do that in my example struct because `array, bool, nil, int, etc` are all `RESERVED` names. There is a separate fix for that if it ever comes up, but I don't see that in your case.

```
struct SampleJsonObject: Codable {
    var someArray: [Int]
    var someBool: Bool
    var someNull: Int?
    var someNum: Int
    var someObj: SomeObject
    var someString: String
}

struct SomeObject: Codable {
    var propA: String
    var propC: String
    var propE: String
}
```

I want you pay particular attention to the `SomeObject` which is a separate structure of another `JSON` object. You can simply think of it as a nested JSON response within the response. I want to point out there's an awesome website, jsonblob.com, that allows you to paste your JSON into it, then `"Beautify"` it so that it'll be easier to read. It'll also make it much easier to determine the difference between an `Array` vs `Object` or `[]` and `{}` in JSON. I see that most often tripping people up. Finally to parse it out, all you need to do is use the code you're already using. In my example, it'll look something like this. Obviously you'll still need to implement the `try catch` block but this should make it much easier, provided you follow the pattern of the original JSON response.

```
 if let decodedRespose = try? JSONDecoder().decode(SampleJsonObject.self, from: data){
                results = decodedRespose.results
```

So given your actual object, that you pasted.

```
{
    "success": true,
    "player": {
        "_id": "asdfasdf131413414",
        "achievements": {
            "b": 10,
            "bedwars_stats": 1034
        }
    }
}
```

Your code would look like this for your `Codable` object.

```
struct Response: Codable {
    var success: Bool
    var player: Player
}

struct Player: Codable {
    var _id: String 
    var achievements: Achievement
}

struct Achievement: Codable {
    var b: Int
    var bedwars_stats: Int
}
```

Which you would decode directly into your `Response` object and it'll take care of the structure for the remainder. What do you do if you want to re-name your variables because either they don't look right, or they're a reserved name? Well the solution to that is `CodingKeys` which is relatively easy to implement. Suppose we want `bedwars_stats` to be `stats` how would we implement that?

```
struct Achievement: Codable {
     //All your other properties
     //This one is your "Renamed" key.
     var stats: Int

    enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
        case stats = "bedwars_stats"
    }
}
```